# Cannot find class [xu.zha.yao.z2.OuterClass$InnerClass] for bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

It is my first time to learn spring,and I   do some pratice,and want to use the function innerMethod to print string "This is InnerClass's Innermethod"
so I use OuterClass.java here:

```
public class OuterClass {
    static class InnerClass {
        public void innerMethod() {
            System.out.println("This is InnerClass's Innermethod");
        }
    }
}
```

and I use the BeanInitialDemo to make a instance.

```
package zhang.you.yao1.z2;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;



/**
  * @ClassName: BeanInitialDemo
  * @Description: TODO
  * @author osxm:oscarxueming
  */

public class BeanInitialDemo {

    /**
      * @Title: main
      * @Description: TODO
      * @param args
      */

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans.xml",BeanInitialDemo.class);
        OuterClass.InnerClass  inner = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
        inner.innerMethod();
    }

}
```

Last ,I write spring-beans.xml here:

```
    <!-- inner Class initial -->
    <bean id="innerObject" class=" xu.zha.yao.z2.OuterClass$InnerClass" />

    
    
    <!-- <bean id="user" class="cn.osxm.ssmi.com.User" c:name="Oscar" c:parent-ref="user1" p:age="30" p:child-ref="user2"/>-->
</beans>
```

but why it give the error,any help is appreciate,thanks:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
> find class [xu.zha.yao.z2.OuterClass$InnerClass] for bean with name
> 'innerObject' defined in class path resource
> [zhang/you/yao1/z2/spring-beans.xml]; nested exception is
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xu.zha.yao.z2.OuterClass$InnerClass
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
> find class [xu.zha.yao.z2.OuterClass$InnerClass] for bean with name
> 'innerObject' defined in class path resource
> [zhang/you/yao1/z2/spring-beans.xml]; nested exception is
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xu.zha.yao.z2.OuterClass$InnerClass

Comment: is my code error,or something?

Comment: it has the class in the output path.